# Descent properties of topological Hochschild homology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, algebraic-k-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry

**Question:** What is the finest topology on $\mathrm{CAlg}$ (commutative ring spectra) for which *THH* (Topological Hochschild Homology) satisfies descent?

Adaptations of the arguments appearing in Section 3 of [BMS2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03261) show that *THH* has flat descent for simplicial commutative rings. However, the methods therein cannot be used to check whether *THH* has flat (or any weaker form of) descent for commutative ring spectra; simplicial $R$-algebras have the special property of being the nonabelian derived category of the category of finitely generated polynomial $R$-algebras.

Comment: Let me guess, CAlg here means is the category of (connective/nonconnective) commutative ring spectra?

Comment: @crystalline This is correct. Maybe I should specify I care about connective things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Theorem 1.2 of B. I. Dundas and J. Rognes: "Cubical and cosimplicial descent", Journal of the London Mathematical Society (2) 98 (2018) 439-460, DOI 10.1112/jlms.12141, we showed that for each $1$-connected map $\phi : A \to B$, of connective commutative $S$-algebras, the map from $THH(A)$ to the homotopy limit of the cosimplicial spectrum
$$
[q] \mapsto THH(B \wedge_A \dots \wedge_A B)
$$
(with $q+1$ copies of $B$) is an equivalence.  Here $1$-connected means that $\pi_0(\phi)$ is an isomorphism and $\pi_1(\phi)$ is surjective.  This should let you reduce the general descent question to the one for (simplcial) commutative rings.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. Are the connectivity requirements absolutely essential for your result?

Comment: The connectivity requirement is necessary for our proof, but not for the conclusion, as [BMS2] show in the case of (discrete) commutative rings.  If $A \to B$ is a map of connective commutative $S$-algebras and $THH$ satisfies descent for $\pi_0(A) \to \pi_0(B)$, then $THH$ satisfies descent for $A \to H\pi_0(A) \to H\pi_0(B)$ and $B \to H\pi_0(B)$.  I would not be surprised if you can use this to deduce that $THH$ satisfies descent for $A \to B$.